# Linq c# multiple group by

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a linq query which would give me this type of result

[image]

So I am trying to Group by order type which could be *Surplus* or *Deficit*. After that I am Grouping by *Region* and then I want to see how much of deficit of each masstype is there. So far I have achieved this

```
var results = Order.GetActive().GroupBy(x => x.OrderType).
        Select(i => new { OrderType = i.Key, Orders = i.ToList().GroupBy(j => j.GetLocation().Region) });
```

Now I am stuck in trying to group it by masstype and then calculate total amount. For example if there are 10 *surplus* orders for *masstype1* I want to show one entry accumulating the amount.

Something like this

```
{
'Region'{

    'Oslo'{

        'Masstype' {

            'Rock' {

                'Defict', 100
                'Surplus', 0
            },
            'Mud' {

                'Defict', 100
                'Surplus', 100
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question, it is difficult to know what format you want the output to be in, however, you can group by multiple properties using an anonymous type like this:

```
var groupedEntries = Order.GetActive().GroupBy(x => new {x.OrderType, x.GetLocation().Region, x.MassType})
```

EDIT: Following the update, it looks like you want a structure something like this: `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>>` which you can achieve with the following LINQ statement, however, at this point, I would recommend creating a new structure to hold this data:

```
var result = Order.GetActive()
    .GroupBy(a => a.OrderType)
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a
        .GroupBy(b => b.GetLocation().Region)
        .ToDictionary(b => b.Key, b => b.
            GroupBy(c => c.MassType)
            .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Sum(d => d.Value))
        )
    );
```

Comment: What I am trying to get is a list containing regions and each region has a list of mass-types with total amount. And all of this divided into deficit and surplus which are order types. hope this explains.

Comment: I'm afraid it still isn't clear to me what the type of that object would be, maybe you could update the question with how you will use it?

Comment: I added a data structure of how I think the end object would look like.

Comment: If this doesn't help, maybe we can take it to private chat. :)

Comment: Thanks mate, I would try this and see if it works, ;)

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks mate. I do have to understand now what is going on in there. :)

Comment: do you mind if I change the data structure a bit and ask you to guide me?

Comment: It would be best to ask another question to keep them clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138805/discussion-between-chaudhry-mohsin-ali-and-tomdoescode).